# LightSwitch - displaying related table information on Create screen

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have `Table1` linked to `Table2` with a `1 to 0..1` relationship. `Table2` is read only, from another data source.

When `Field1` (which defines a key to `Table2`) is entered in an entry screen, I would like to have the `Table2` data on the screen show the results that match `Field1`.

For Example:
`Table1` is "WidgetProblem"
`Table2` is "Widget"

When the user enters the Widget ID in the Widget Problem screen, I want the details of the widget to show up on the screen, without first having to save and then edit / display the screen.  I want the user to see the Widget information so that they can be sure they've got the correct widget.

The fields are all there, I just can't quite figure out how to trigger the data lookup "early".  Back in the day I would just handle this on an event from the field, kick off a quick populate of the fields on the screen and be done.  Obviously it's not the same in LightSwitch.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Thanks for the cleanup "bytebuster".  First time poster, gotta get up to speed on how to correctly user StackOverflow! :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing as you've already created the relationship between the tables, the *WidgetProblem* table/entity should have an added *navigation property*, more than likely called *Widget* (if you didn't change the name). You shouldn't need to be dealing with IDs yourself.

When you drag one of these *navigation properties* (from the left-hand side in the screen designer, over to the control tree), LightSwitch will display an *AutoCompleteBox* (a fancy name for a *ComboBox*) for you, so the user will be able to choose the desired *Widget* from a list of widget names, & the ID is automatically stored for you.

You sometimes really do have to "forget" what you already know from other technologies when you start to use LightSwitch. Trying to do things the way you would in those other technologies can cause frustration, until you learn to do things "the LightSwitch way".

This set of beginner videos, [LightSwitch How Do I Videos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/gg702681), made by Beth Massi, should give you a good grounding of the various techniques that you'll need to get you started successfully creating LS applications.

Comment: Yann, thanks for the complete answer (my apologies for the delay - I don't think I got notified!).  The problem is that there are 500,000 widgets and they are just sequence #'s, so a combobox would be suboptimal for this...  I watched the Massi videos before and they are definitely a good intro.  Leave it to me to head straight into an edge case!  I guess you could think of the "widgets" as cars.  They are all the same thing (cars) but each one is unique for the purposes of tracking issues with them. Need to make sure the user got the right "car"...

Comment: Well, you could use a ModalWindowPicker instead of an ACB. A MWP is designed for cases where an ACB would have too many rows. Have a look at the MWP control & it might be what you need.

Comment: I'll take a loot at it over the weekend.  Thanks again!

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I want to do same